# How to use switch case in SQL

Tags: php, oracle

I have two Oracle sql statements which decide by the CUR_STATUS.  Is there any other way that I can combined two into one with Switch case to produce the below presentation (if no records found then will display "No previous owner records found. else will list the Name： Gender:  )?

REGISTERED OWNER
Name:
Gender:

Name:
Gender:

Name:
Gender:

.
.
.

PREVIOUS OWNER:  No previous owner records found.

```
SELECT a.TRN,
a.OWN_NAME,
a.GENDER,
FROM a, b
WHERE b.CUR_STATUS = 'Y'
and b.ID_NUM = a.ID_NUM
ORDER BY b.TRN;


SELECT a.TRN,
a.OWN_NAME,
a.GENDER,
FROM a, b
WHERE b.CUR_STATUS = 'N'
and b.ID_NUM = a.ID_NUM
ORDER BY b.TRN;
```

Comment: Thanks Cecilia Thomson.  The two queries appear to be identical; I wondered if they are supposed to be different?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did not get why you have used the same query times, yet if you want to use `CASE` statement then below might be your solution for you.

```
CASE b.CUR_STATUS
 WHEN 'Y'
  THEN SELECT a.TRN,
              a.OWN_NAME,
              a.GENDER,
  FROM a, b WHERE b.ID_NUM = a.ID_NUM
  ORDER BY b.TRN;
 ELSE 'No previous owner records found';
END CASE
```